# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVPlayerItem duration]: unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, core-audio, avplayer, mpmediaitem

I am trying to play a MediaItem using AVPlayer and later trying to get the duration of the current item like this (duration is an object of type CMTime):

```
duration = [[player currentItem] duration];
```

I get no issues in iPad but in iPod Touch, I get the following error. I haven't tried this in iPhone yet.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVPlayerItem duration]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x186100'

Any pointers to the fix will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're most likely testing this on an iPod with iOS < 4.3.

According to the `AVPlayerItem` documentation, `duration` is only available in iOS 4.3 or later.

Comment: Oops! Yeah. I was testing in an iPod with iOS 4.0. Is there any other way to get the AVPlayerItem's duration?

Comment: `duration = [[[player currentItem] asset] duration];`

Comment: I am always getting the duration as 0. I am trying to play a song from the iPod library. How do I get the duration in this case?

Comment: If it's an `MPMediaItem` you can do `[item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];`

Comment: Cool. +1 to you edc1591. That really helps!