# Ideal method to get the duration of an AVPlayerItem in iOS 4.0

Tags: ios, ios4, core-audio, avplayer

What is the ideal way of getting the duration of an AVPlayerItem in iOS 4.0? The duration property for AVPlayerItem is only available in iOS 4.3 and later. `[[[player currentItem] asset] duration];` is always returning 0 for me. I am trying to play a song from the iPod library.

Comment: `player.currentItem.duration` will work only in iOS 4.3 and later.

Comment: What does `player.currentItem.asset.tracks.count` return?

Comment: If it is an `MPMediaItem`, it can be done by `[item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];`. See the reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9287442/846075